# Consulta Mysql 3 tablas con Inner Join

Tags: php, html, sql, join

Hola comunidad tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando crear una tabla de listas de precios a partir de las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE `Producto` (
  `pkProducto` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombreProducto` text NOT NULL,
  `precioCompra` text,
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `ListaPrecio` (
  `pkListaPrecio` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombreListaPrecio` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkListaPrecio`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `listaPrecioProducto` (
  `fkListaPrecio` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `fkProducto` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `ganancia` int DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

El resultado que quiero ver es cada producto con sus precios en lista hacia la derecha

| pkProducto | nombreProducto | Lista precio | Ganancia | Lista precio | Ganancia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | producto1 | lista 1 | 30% | lista 2 | 50% |
| 2 | producto2 | lista 1 | 25% | lista 2 | 5% |

Sin embargo la consulta que tengo me arroja la lista hacía abajo cuando hago las relaciones:

```
SELECT T1.pkProducto, T1.nombreProducto, T2.nombreListaPrecio, T2.Ganancia
FROM Producto T1
inner join ListaPrecioProducto T2 ON T1.intProducto = T2.intProducto
```

Resultando:

| pkProducto | nombreProducto | Lista precio | Ganancia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | producto1 | lista 1 | 30% |
| 1 | producto1 | lista 2 | 50% |
| 2 | producto2 | lista 1 | 25% |
| 2 | producto2 | lista 2 | 5% |

No estoy realmente seguro si esto se pueda hacer directamente desde SQL o tenga que meter algo de lógica en el HTML con PHP al momento de crear las tablas.

Comment: Parece que quieres una fila por producto no? Puedes utilizar group by y utilizar en el select funciones como MAX, SUM,...

Comment: Esto se puede hacer, tanto en SQL como en PHP. Pero conviene aclarar lo siguiente: *La idea es que esta tabla pueda crecer dinámica-mente a la derecha mientras las listas de precio crezcan.* Si en un futuro habrá muchas listas, me parece poco práctico presentar columnas interminables, a no ser que lo vayas a imprimir en un panel enorme de varios metros para analizar los datos desde un helicoptero o algo así :). Teniendo eso claro podremos ayudarte mejor. ¿Qué justifica presentar datos en horizontal en este caso? ¿De cuántas listas podríamos estar hablando, de 5, de 10, de 500?

Comment: La cantidad de listas estaría variando entre 2 y 15, (Actualmente hay 7) dudo mucho se lleguen a requerir mas de esas, por ello la idea es que la tabla pueda crecer a la derecha mientras se vayan agregando nuevas listas; la finalidad es que estas desaparezcan cuando ya no se necesiten y también aparezcan las nuevas en el momento que son creadas.

Comment: Es facila hacer un inner join entre variablas tablas desde que esten relacionadas mediante una llave foranea, pero de donde sale Lista Precio 2?

Comment: Amigo parece que falta una tabla estuve mirando lo que puiste y no enttiendo de donde sacas Lista Precio 2 y Ganacia 2 ?